# Need a text editor that can allow the user to view at least 6 text panes at a time, & can save all panes into a single file, or func. equivalent

Tags: text-editor

One way it could do this is if the software had savable sessions and tabs, and each tab could have its own text pane. Or maybe the window would just have six panes, where the software has no tab feature. Either works. I don't mind if I have to get plugins for a software in order to do this.

I prefer something simple and accessible, which can open and close new and old files with minimal steps, easily enough that you don't have to think too hard about it, like the basic Windows Notepad program.

I tried Notepad++; it only offers the ability to have two 'views' at the same time, which is not enough for me. If there is a new plugin which could accommodate my needs though, I welcome the recommendation; still have npp installed.

Recommendations which are not Emacs or Vim are preferred

Comment: Why not (g)vim ? What are the disadvantages for you that you explicitly exclude it rule it out?

Comment: Vim has the hard learning curve.

Comment: @RProgram question is do you want to have some limiting capabilities or invest for a powerful tool for future use as well.

Comment: @albert I need big capabilities, with the usual learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** editor (free) has so called groups, you can change group mode via “=“ top menu item. It has mode “6 groups”, you can try it.
It allows to open 6 different files, not 6 views of the same file.

Last release has 6 groups vertically or horizontally, screenshot:
[image: CudaText]

About saving to a single file - plugin **CudaExt** allows it with its command "Plugins/ Cuda-Ext/ File/ Save editors to a single file". Screenshot:

[image: CudaExt]

Comment: Please provide a link to CudaText. Are you related / creator of CudaText (I see a .com address).

Comment: Are you related to CudaText in any way? If yes please disclose it, thanks!

Comment: I was hoping it would allow 6 tall panes arranged at equal 'altitude' on the screen, spread out in a row

Comment: @Veqen Added info about last beta,  with 6 groups vertically

Comment: Answer was improved to show CudaText plugin which can "save all editors to a single file".